# How to edit Active-Directory Site properties via Powershell?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I am having trouble accessing the `location` property of my Active-Directory's Site via Powershell. (Windows Server 2012 R2)

The following command returns no value:
`> (Get-ADReplicationSite "Default-First-Site-Name" | Get-ADObject).location`

This command returns an identifier:
`> (Get-ADReplicationSite "Default-First-Site-Name" | Get-ADObject).objectGUID`

When I am looking into the graphical *Attribute Editor* of the object in the *Active Directory Sites and Services* Snap-In, **I can verify by the objectGUID-propterty, that I do query the correct AD object and that the location-property is filled**.

So why does Powershell return no value and how do I query and edit the `location` attribute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because [`Get-ADObject` does not retrieve all attributes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617198.aspx) by default:

> The Get-ADObject cmdlet **returns a default set of ADObject property values**. To retrieve additional ADObject properties, use the Properties parameter of the cmdlet.

The `objectGUID` property has a value because it's part of [the default property set](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12103.active-directory-get-adobject-default-and-extended-properties.aspx)

---

You can specify additional properties for `Get-ADObject` to retrieve with the `-Properties` parameter:

```
(Get-ADReplicationSite "Default-First-Site-Name" | Get-ADObject -Properties location).location
```